# App Inventor 2: Runtime error list index smaller than 1

Tags: app-inventor

[image]

I have a problem

I want to change the background image every second

Please help me

Comment: well, each time the timer event fires, you decrement the index. After 5 times it will be < 1... what about adding an if statement like this `if global time = 0 then global time = 4`?

Comment: note: in App Inventor the maximum value of an index is 1!

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me. I have tested it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I got it from QuizMe Tutorial, It's a loop list.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXxU2.png)